# Значение слова "экскурс"

Tags: значение-слов

Понадобилось уточнить значение слова "экскурс" и обнаружилось, что в словарях значения разные.

> Толковый словарь Ожегова.

экскурс - изучение, освещение какого-нибудь специального вопроса, связанного с главной темой 
Пример: Краткий э. в историю.

> Ефремова Т.Ф. Толковый словарь русского языка.

экскурс
м.
Отступление от главной темы изложения для освещения, разработки побочного 
вопроса.

Или слова "побочный вопрос" и "специальный вопрос" здесь означает одно и то же? И все равно слова "связанные с главной темой", "отступление от главной темы" воспринимаются как антонимы. 
Как бы вы сформулировали значение слова?

Comment: Здравствуйте,  давненько вас не было )). А в чем вы видите столь принципиальную разницу между определениями? По-моему у Ефремовой просто современным языком сформулировано,

Comment: И я Вам рада... Не знаю, прочитала "отступление от главной темы" и "связанные с главной темой" как противоположные по смыслу.

Comment: A, ясно! Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Экскурс - это контекстно связанное отступление от главной темы. Как правило, задача экскурса - дать знание об исторической эпохе или предыстории рассматриваемого материала.

Например, изучая "Что делать?", преподаватель может сделать исторический экскурс про цензоров и объяснить, как так получилось, что роман оказался напечатан. Эта тема будет и побочной, и специальной, так что оба словаря пишут об одном и том же.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ уже дали, я только по поводу токования слов, вызвавших сомнения. 
В данном контексте "побочный" и "специальный" - практически синонимы. Т.е. разница есть, но достачно тонкая, для практики не существенная.

Думаю, что затруднение связно со словом "специальный". Я когда-то с ним разбирался по этому поводу.

С некоторых пор слово "специальный" все более более теряет значение "частный, отдельный" (в пользу "профильный") - и у Ефремовой замененно на "побочный", но во времена Ожегова, ручаюсь, такое значение было еще на слуху.

Вот посмотрите, как Кузнецов толкует
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x

А вот как Ожегов.
http://slovarozhegova.ru/word.php?wordid=30101

Ясно, что в понимании последнего "специальный" (в 1-м значении) вполне тянет на "побочный".

Upd

> Не знаю, прочитала "отступление от главной темы" и "связанные с главной темой" как противоположные по смыслу.

A! Так слушайте, слона-то, я и не приметил (((. Посыпаю пеплом седины. Да, "связанный" и "отстуление" в некотором роде антонимы". Но в общем-то я тем не менее ответил достаточно близко к сути.  Слово "специального" у Ожегова по тогдашней семантике берет на себя значение, выражаемое "отступлением" у Ефремовой. Т.е. в обоих случаях можно сказать, что это вопрос ***связанный*** с главной темой, но тем не менее - ***побочный***, не лежащий в основном её русле.